# Old javascript slide show wihtout slide just (onclick)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, slideshow

Hello I need to switch image up with a button like a slide show but no need to slide, I have try something and want someone to help me with the kind of code. I'm doing this

```
 <img id="imageswitch" src="image/1.jpg" width="400" height="286" alt="photo1" />
<script>

var image = document.getElementById("imageswitch")

    function switchImage(){
        if(image.src = "image/1.jpg"){
            image.src = "image/2.jpg";

        }else if(image.src = "image/2.jpg"){
            image.src = "image/3.jpg";
            console.log("marche")
        }else{
            console.log("dont work man")
        }
}

 document.getElementById("boutonright").addEventListener("click", function () {
        switchImage();
  });
```

Comment: @RobG No, this is not even remotely on-topic for Code Review. This is a feature request, not a request for review. Keep it here.

Answer (score 1):

- Put your images paths into an array.
- On button click manipulate your array:

```js
var image = document.getElementById("imageswitch"),
    images = [
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/fb0/?text=1",
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/0bf/?text=2",
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/bf0/?text=3"
    ];

function switchImage(){
  images.push( images.shift() );
  image.src = images[0];
}

document.getElementById("boutonright").addEventListener("click", switchImage);
```

```css
#imageswitch{height:180px;}
```

```html
<button id="boutonright">NEXT</button><br>
<img id="imageswitch" src="http://placehold.it/400x286/fb0/?text=1" alt="photo1" />
```

---

If you want to have both `PREV` and `NEXT` buttons:

```js
var image = document.getElementById("imageswitch"),
    images = [
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/fb0/?text=1",
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/0bf/?text=2",
      "http://placehold.it/400x286/bf0/?text=3"
    ];

function switchImage(){
  if(this.id==="next") images.push( images.shift() );
  else /* id==="prev*/ images.unshift( images.pop() );
  image.src = images[0];
}

document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", switchImage);
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", switchImage);
```

```css
#imageswitch{height:180px;}
```

```html
<button id="prev">PREV</button><button id="next">NEXT</button><br>
<img id="imageswitch" src="http://placehold.it/400x286/fb0/?text=1" alt="photo1" />
```